# Find the lowest non-contiguous value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was asked to write a T-SQL statement that will find the lowest unused value of `MyId` in the sequence below (i.e. in this case the result should be 3):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (MyId INT);

INSERT INTO @MyTable(MyId) VALUES(1),(2),(4),(5);
```

Comment: That is a terrible interview question!

Comment: @DaveMarkle: It depends on the position the interview was for; for some positions, it would be a decent question.

Comment: I still think it's pretty terrible.  What are the assumptions?  That  it's only those data?  Are you really being tasked with finding just one gap, or an arbitrary number of gaps?  And "unused value" is a pretty hideous way to phrase the question.

Comment: I'm with Ken here.. I don't think that's a bad question at all. There are many ways you can skin this cat... they want to know how you attack the problem. I think it's a much better question than "tell me what a clustered index is?"

Comment: @DaveMarkle It is for a trainee database developer role. I have to agree with Dave on this one, it's a terrible question. I mean, I just graduated and only have graduate level when it comes to sql. So you can imagine my face when I saw this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
;With CTE
AS
(
SELECT   * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyID ASC) AS RN 
FROM @MyTable
)
SELECT TOP 1 rn
FROM CTE
WHERE Rn <> MyId
ORDER BY MyId ASC
```

Comment: true just noticed it now :)

Comment: @YuriyGalanter on a side note is there any difference in using <> Vs != , it think its only ANSI and non ANSI syntax isnt it ??

Comment: Cheers @AaronBertrand I always learn something when your around :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you very informative and interesting read + 1 :)

Comment: Upvoted your answer.  ...Aaaaand this is why I think this is a terrible question.  The question only asks you to find a "missing" value (whatever that means).  Making the assumption (not in the question) that a "missing" value means actually "find the gap", and given the set of numbers which have the gap you assumed the question meant, this answer answers the question perfectly and will return 3.    @YuriyGalanter makes a different assumption as to what the question means which may or may not be valid.  Ergo, it's a hideously bad question to ask someone for an interview!

Comment: @DaveMarkle I totally agree with you on this, I think any questions asked in a job interview is only to get some idea how a candidate approaches a problem. They wont be expecting him to give the exact answer, what they had in their minds, but to see what approach candidate takes and can he really think out of the box :) , it really is a bit silly/awkward/tricky question isnt it :)

Comment: @MuhammedAli: I think you give these interviewers too much credit :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would probably answer that question (though it is impossible for anyone here to know exactly what the interviewer was after).

First, you can easily generate a sequence of contiguous numbers from existing tables or views in any SQL Server system. For this, let's use `master..spt_values` (which will cover a sequence of about 2000 values, depending on version):

```
SELECT TOP (5) n = number + 1
  FROM master.dbo.spt_values
  WHERE type = N'P'
  ORDER BY number;
```

Results:

```
n
------
1
2
3
4
5
```

Now, you don't know in advance that you need 5, so you can determine the number you need by taking the min and max from the table:

```
DECLARE @min INT, @max INT;

SELECT @min = MIN(MyId), @max = MAX(MyId) FROM @MyTable;
```

Now you can get the exact set you need (since it may not always start at 1):

```
SELECT TOP (@max-@min+1) number 
  FROM master.dbo.spt_values
  WHERE number >= @min AND type = N'P'
  ORDER BY number;
```

Now, finally, we can perform a left anti-semi-join to find the first value that exists in our contiguous set but not in the table:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (@max-@min+1) number 
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE number >= @min AND type = N'P'
    ORDER BY number
)
SELECT MIN(number) FROM x
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM @MyTable WHERE MyId = x.number);
```

If you need more than 2000 values, you can use other things like `sys.all_columns` and if that isn't enough you can `CROSS JOIN` multiple tables. See http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-1, http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-2 and http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-3.

Of course, if you know the sequence *should* always start at 1, rather than the minimum value in the table, then the other answers are slightly simpler. This caters to the case where the set doesn't necessarily start with 1, and you don't care about "missing" values that are below the minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to find first non-sequential number for a sequence that strats with (assumingly) with 1. You can do this by comparing to sequential numbers, generated by ROW_NUMBER() function

```
SELECT TOP(1) RN FROM

  (SELECT MyID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyId) AS RN FROM @MyTable) MT

WHERE MyID <> RN
ORDER BY MyID ASC
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1a90/2

Comment: Yuriy, don't you have to add "order by MyID asc" to the end of your answer?

Comment: @samyi thanks, but in my tests internal `OVER (ORDER BY MyId)` was enough. Could u plz show a sample where the above won't work?

Comment: "was enough" is the same thing people said when they relied on `ORDER BY` in a view and didn't bother adding `ORDER BY` to the outer queries that referenced the view. They changed their tune when, without changing schema or code, their ordering no longer worked when they upgraded from 2000 to any newer version. Always, always, always put `ORDER BY` on the outer query. The goal is to ensure your ordering works *as defined*, not *as observed*. Just because you can't prove that wasting 13 whole characters won't break your query now doesn't mean that will always be true.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Good point. Updated. @ samyi thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
select MyId, row_number over (order by MyId asc) RowId
from @MyTable
)

select top 1 c1.MyId + 1 FirstMissingMyId
from cte c1
join cte c2
  on c1.RowId + 1 = c2.RowId
where c1.MyId + 1 <> c2.MyId
order by c1.MyId asc
```